# how to set the path during local report processing report defintion in WPF that can be bind with setup

Tags: wpf

> **how to set the file path of report during local report processing**

```
    private void btnReport_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {                             
                    if (!_isReportViewerLoaded)
                    {
```

> Tbl_SensorDataSet is an Dataset that have Tbl_SensorDataSetTableadapter

```
                        Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource reportDataSource1;
                        Tbl_SensorDataSet dataset;
                        string query = Reportingquery;
                        dataset = new Tbl_SensorDataSet();
                        reportDataSource1 = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource();
                        Tbl_SensorDataSetTableAdapters.GetFilterReadingTableAdapter TableAdapter1 = new Tbl_SensorDataSetTableAdapters.GetFilterReadingTableAdapter();
                        TableAdapter1.ClearBeforeFill = true;
                        TableAdapter1.Fill(dataset.GetFilterReading, query);
                        dataset.BeginInit();
                        reportDataSource1.Name = "DataSet1";
                        reportDataSource1.Value = dataset.GetFilterReading;
                        this._reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource1);                            
                        this._reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = "../../SensorReport.rdlc";
                        dataset.EndInit();
                        _reportViewer.RefreshReport();
                        _isReportViewerLoaded = true;
                    }
                }

        catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; }            
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ReportEmbeddedResource` instead of `ReportPath`, because `ReportPath` looks for the file existence and `ReportEmbeddedResource` looks into the assembly resource as a fully qualified object name.

Here is the sample:

```
report.ReportEmbeddedResource = full Namespace.report.rdlc
```

Comment: this._reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "IntelliOpticsReport.MainWindow.SensorReport.rdlc";

Comment: i use its but not Get rdlc file

Comment: yes it should work else what you can do is mark you report copy local if newer in build opetion and then you can use the reportpath property of the report.reportpath.

Comment: mainwindow in your namespace above is the window or namespace the namespace is required for the report file not for the report object